# Initializing a 2-dimensions array in a domain class

Tags: grails

I am trying to represent a 16*16 grid in a domain class. Currently the grid is represented by a one-dimension array. This works:

```
class Grid {

    List cells = []

    static hasMany = [cells:Cell]

    void init() {
        // Initialize cells
        for(int x = 0; x < 16*16 ; x++) {
            addToCells(new Cell())
        }
    }    

}
```

But what is the right way to create a two-dimensions array? Also, is there a way of initializing all the cells without iterating?

Comment: and also you want to store such relation as 2-d in db, right?

Comment: yes! all the cells need to be saved

Comment: Why not just store a 1d array and the width, then you can use mod and intdiv to get elements by rows/columns

Comment: Or collate to get back a 2d array when you need it? Ie: `cells.collate(width)`

Comment: Do you need random access to single cells, or do you access many of the cells of your matrix? This is also related to the size of your matrix, if it is manageable in memory or not.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert how do you see it in db? tables structure, relations

Comment: @tim_yates, good idea. I would definitely do that even though I still want to know how we would have implemented a 2-d array here.

Comment: @loteq, random access is what I need. I will access the cells from a known coordinate (x,y). The size of the matrix is assigned only once and all the cells maintain their place.

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert how big is this matrix? If you are accessing a couple of cells in a huge matrix, using the collate approach seems wasteful. If you are accessing most of the cells or the matrix is small, it is a very good approach

Comment: You are right, it definitely looks like the thriftiest approach in my case. @tim_yates, would you like to write an answer? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A domain class represents an entity that is mapped onto an underlying database table. I realized it had no point in storing a 2D array as such in a database.

As @Tim_Yates suggested in the comments, it's better to use the `collate` method. I've kept the 1D array as a property and can still access a proper 2D-representation of the grid using:

```
Cell[][] cellz = cells.collate(edgeSize)
Cell myCell = cellz[5][9]
```